# cross-reference chapter title from different file

Tags: cross-referencing, external-files

My dissertation is several chapters, each written in a different .tex file. How can I reference the chapter number from one chapter in the text of another? For example, how would I produce

> '... will be discussed more thoroughly in chapter 3.'

where '3' is dynamically generated based on its order in the list of chapters included (using `\include`) in the master file?

Comment: this is basic functionality- use `\chapter{your title here}\label{anynameyouwantnospaces}` and then `\ref{anynameyouwantnospaces}`. also check out the `cleveref` and `varioref` packages

Comment: I've done what cmhughes suggested, but it leaves me with **??** in place of the `\ref` command. I'm compiling with XeLaTeX, if that makes a difference.

Comment: compile it again :)

Comment: I have. Several times. It's a poorly-written template, required by the University. Could that be affecting things? I compile using a batch file: XeLaTeX, XeLaTeX, BibTeX, XeLaTeX, XeLaTeX. But it won't let me dynamically reference labels in other chapters (specifically, the **chapter** label).

Comment: BTW, if you want to cross-reference your *title*, that is the actual words of the title and not only its numeral reference, you can use [`nameref`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/hyperref/nameref.pdf) (which is a part of `hyperref`).

Answer (score 2):

Just do it! This is how my thesis is organised. In each separate chapter file, start with something like

```
\chapter{Introduction}
\label{chap:intro}
```

Then in your next chapter you just do `\ref{chap:intro}`

By the way, you might want to check out the `import` package: I have each chapter in a subdirectory and the figures for each chapter in their own subdirectories. `import` and in particular the command `subimport` makes it all much neater.

Answer (score 0):

I just use `\input` not `\include` then you can compile one document with all cross references and a correct list of references. If you need to compile only that chapter you can use make a chapter specific file like the main thesis file but eliminate the other chapters (comment out). You can also reset the chapter counter if you want for providing to your advisor and such. See [Input vs Include Discussion for more information](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246/when-should-i-use-input-vs-include%22Include%20vs%20input%22)

Comment: If you use `\include` you have `\includeonly`, so no need to comment out.